# Как получить id обьекта внутри views.py приложения на django?

Tags: django

Как получить id обьекта внутри views.py приложения на django?

Например:

есть 
person = Person.objects.all()
а
ptrson.id не выдает.

Comment: Если вы используете Person.objects.all(), то подходящее имя переменной - **persons** (мн. ч.). Такое имя уже в ходе написания *persons.id* заставит задуматься: идентификатор какой именно из персоналий вы желаете получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person.objects.all() - выборка всех объектов модели Person. Id первого объекта в списке можно получить так:

```
Person.objects.all()[0].id
```